# Why elementary platform is installed multiple times? Should I remove all oldest?

Tags: flatpak

I am trying to save space from my device and I was running out of memory despite cleaning `apt` and `snap`. When I checked `flatpak`, I discovered that it unnecessarily uses huge amount of memory which I want to reclaim. Are all `io.elementary.Platform` packages, installed by elementary OS, necessary? If not, Should I remove anything below `7.2`?

```
$ flatpak list --all --show-details
… … … Version  Branch      Arch   Origin      Installation Ref                                                     Active commit Latest commit Installed size …
… … … 1.1.7    stable      x86_64 appcenter   user         com.github.alexkdeveloper.raddiola/x86_64/stable        3282b8e4df42  -             318.0 kB       …
…  …          stable      x86_64 appcenter   user         com.github.alexkdeveloper.raddiola.Locale/x86_64/stable e3a21dfed203  -             512 bytes      …
… … … 1.1.5    stable      x86_64 appcenter   user         com.github.donadigo.appeditor/x86_64/stable             ad749df06aae  -               8.3 MB       …
…  …          stable      x86_64 appcenter   user         com.github.donadigo.appeditor.Locale/x86_64/stable      ec33065d9a6b  -             512 bytes      …
…  …          6           x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.Platform/x86_64/6                         dc72c0942e0d  -               1.0 GB       …
…  …          6.1         x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.Platform/x86_64/6.1                       be2732301d0d  -             812.0 MB       …
…  …          7           x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.Platform/x86_64/7                         10334eac481d  -             806.1 MB       …
…  …          7           x86_64 appcenter   user         io.elementary.Platform/x86_64/7                         10334eac481d  -             806.1 MB       …
…  …          7.1         x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.Platform/x86_64/7.1                       4f56a6ec546e  -             900.1 MB       …
…  …          7.2         x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.Platform/x86_64/7.2                       c84622ed58e4  -             897.7 MB       …
…  …          6           x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.Platform.Locale/x86_64/6                  b7a3eafc152d  -               1.3 GB       …
…  …          6.1         x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.Platform.Locale/x86_64/6.1                970a9ea4ad6a  -               1.4 GB       …
…  …          7           x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.Platform.Locale/x86_64/7                  0d26b62574d7  -             188.6 MB       …
…  …          7           x86_64 appcenter   user         io.elementary.Platform.Locale/x86_64/7                  0d26b62574d7  -             512 bytes      …
…  …          7.1         x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.Platform.Locale/x86_64/7.1                c61739f7e4e6  -              71.2 kB       …
…  …          7.2         x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.Platform.Locale/x86_64/7.2                73edf646fc24  -              71.2 kB       …
… … … 2.0.2    stable      x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.calculator/x86_64/stable                  bb48fdc8e1ae  -             695.8 kB       …
…  …          stable      x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.calculator.Locale/x86_64/stable           c8bbbb46218c  -             192.5 kB       …
… … … 6.2.2    stable      x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.camera/x86_64/stable                      72401c2f87b4  -               1.2 MB       …
…  …          stable      x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.camera.Locale/x86_64/stable               726d558e3816  -             100.9 kB       …
… … … 2.4.4    stable      x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.capnet-assist/x86_64/stable               df11efbc663f  -             655.4 kB       …
…  …          stable      x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.capnet_assist.Locale/x86_64/stable        59d93f9105f5  -             150.5 kB       …
… … … 6.0.4    stable      x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.screenshot/x86_64/stable                  889115dc05b3  -             732.7 kB       …
…  …          stable      x86_64 appcenter   system       io.elementary.screenshot.Locale/x86_64/stable           d9ddacb3aeca  -             512 bytes      …
… … … 1.4.16   stable      x86_64 flathub     system       md.obsidian.Obsidian/x86_64/stable                      998272fadebf  -             586.3 MB       …
…  …          stable      x86_64 flathub     system       md.obsidian.Obsidian.Locale/x86_64/stable               7b041d380f30  -             512 bytes      …
… … … 22.08.19 22.08       x86_64 flathub     system       org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/22.08                   12e6f0416b1a  -             569.0 MB       …
… … … 23.08.6  23.08       x86_64 flathub     system       org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/23.08                   75d6f5f7daf4  -             591.3 MB       …
… … … 21.3.9   21.08       x86_64 freedesktop system       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default/x86_64/21.08        307acd90a918  -             381.6 MB       …
… … … 23.1.9   22.08       x86_64 flathub     system       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default/x86_64/22.08        160710122096  -             424.1 MB       …
… … … 23.1.9   22.08-extra x86_64 flathub     system       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default/x86_64/22.08-extra  8311dc516d6b  -             424.1 MB       …
… … … 23.2.1   23.08       x86_64 flathub     system       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default/x86_64/23.08        dcbdd21fd79e  -             484.9 MB       …
… … … 23.2.1   23.08-extra x86_64 flathub     system       org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default/x86_64/23.08-extra  508ed21fd9fe  -             484.9 MB       …
…  …          22.08       x86_64 flathub     system       org.freedesktop.Platform.Locale/x86_64/22.08            8f2876a9b5bc  -              79.9 kB       …
…  …          23.08       x86_64 flathub     system       org.freedesktop.Platform.Locale/x86_64/23.08            18905a9f143d  -               9.2 kB       …
…  …          21.08       x86_64 flathub     system       org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel/x86_64/21.08       2e4d954e4ca3  -              46.5 MB       …
…  …          22.08       x86_64 flathub     system       org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel/x86_64/22.08       a712cc35b56d  -              46.5 MB       …
…  …          23.08       x86_64 flathub     system       org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel/x86_64/23.08       6197e42f4e5e  -              46.5 MB       …
… … … 2.1.0    2.0         x86_64 flathub     system       org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264/x86_64/2.0            bdc77b1e945d  -             778.2 kB       …
… … … 2.1.0    2.2.0       x86_64 flathub     system       org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264/x86_64/2.2.0          bf24f23f3ba3  -             790.0 kB       …
…  …          stable      x86_64 flathub     system       org.gnome.BreakTimer.Locale/x86_64/stable               b2336e2e466f  -             512 bytes      …
… … … 45.0     stable      x86_64 appcenter   system       org.gnome.Evince/x86_64/stable                          ec578375680e  -              31.1 MB       …
…  …          stable      x86_64 appcenter   system       org.gnome.Evince.Locale/x86_64/stable                   bc613899ccca  -               3.9 MB       …
… … … 43.0     stable      x86_64 appcenter   system       org.gnome.FileRoller/x86_64/stable                      823503629173  -              28.6 MB       …
…  …          stable      x86_64 appcenter   system       org.gnome.FileRoller.Locale/x86_64/stable               492a298a998a  -               2.6 MB       …
… … …          43          x86_64 flathub     system       org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/43                            72c5f3d0de59  -             863.8 MB       …
…  …          43          x86_64 flathub     system       org.gnome.Platform.Locale/x86_64/43                     910fb134dfb9  -              71.2 kB       …
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$flatpak uninstall --unused`. as per [david's suggestion](https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/discussions/2138#discussioncomment-8861311)

Answer (score 0):

That's the problem with the sandboxed environment. You can have three small apps that you use daily, like an image viewer, PDF viewer, and music app.
These three apps together can use a few tens of MBs of your drive, but they all may need their environment to run so you could end up with three different Gnome versions, v44, v45, and v46 that use a few GBs of your drive if each app needs a different environment.